# Get product ID inside a custom WooCommerce/Plugin filter

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to change the product edit url which is created from this plugins function:

```
function dokan_edit_product_url( $product ) {
    if ( ! $product instanceof WC_Product ) {
        $product = wc_get_product( $product );
    }
    if ( ! $product ) {
        return false;
    }
    if ( 'publish' === $product->get_status() ) {
        $url = trailingslashit( get_permalink( $product->get_id() ) ) . 'edit/';
    } else {
        $url = add_query_arg(
            [
                'product_id' => $product->get_id(),
                'action'     => 'edit',
            ],
            dokan_get_navigation_url( 'products' )
        );
    }
    return apply_filters( 'dokan_get_edit_product_url', $url, $product );
}
```

You can see it has a `apply_filters` available. So I am trying to create a filter to modify the URL to be: `example.com/edit-product/product-id`

```
add_filter( 'dokan_get_edit_product_url', function() {

  // I need to get the PRODUCT ID here somehow.
  $url = 'example.com/dashboard/edit-product' . $product_id;

  return $url;

} );
```

How can I get the product ID in my filter? I need to grab the product ID and attach it to: `example.com/dashboard/edit-product/` + `product_id`

Here is one attempt:

```
add_filter( 'dokan_get_edit_product_url', function( $product ) {

  $product = wc_get_product( $product );
  var_dump($product);

  return $url;

} );
```

Result:

```
/app/filters.php:175:boolean false
```

Comment: try using `global $product`

Comment: @HowardE - perfect, that's what I was missing, thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following a suggestion in the comments from @howard-e, I was simply missing `global $product;`

Here is my full filter:

```
add_filter( 'dokan_get_edit_product_url', function( $product ) {

  global $product;

  $url = dokan_get_navigation_url() . 'edit-product?product_id=' . $product->get_id();

  return $url;

} );
```

Obviously the format of the $url is unique to my set up, but worth posting the full code anyway.